# Get Theme Attribute from Application Class

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-styles, android-attributes

I have been using a method to obtain color attributes from the current `Context`:

```
public static int getColorAttribute(Context context, @AttrRes int attr) {
    final TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

It works perfectly, but when I tried using it in my class that extends `Application` it returns `0`. In most cases I would call the method like so:

```
int colorAccent = Util.getColorAttribute(this, R.attr.colorAccent);
```

This would return the `"colorAccent"` that I set in `themes.xml` as my `AppTheme` in my Manifest. But in the `Application` class I had to call `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`. So I switched one of my other instances of the method in an `Activity` to `getApplicationContext()` as well and it returned `0`. I also tried `getApplication()` and `getBaseContext()` with the same result.

I was wondering if there is a way to get a color from the application theme in the `Application` class. Or if not, why `getApplicationContext().getTheme()` does not seem to return the application theme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try to set the theme yourself?

```
getApplicationContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.someTheme, true);
```

and then in styles have your theme that is a child of some theme you want in android.  Also this method should be frowned on as themes are meant to be accessed from activity context. application context is not complete for UI tasks.

Comment: That works! Also, technically I'm not using it for a UI task, I'm using it to set the color for the notification icon. I could use `getColor()` but I wanted to keep it relative to the color accent in case it ever changes. In any case, should I not be doing this in my `Application` class? Maybe my `MainActivity` or `PreferenceActivity` instead? I am only doing it in my `Application` class because that is where I am setting up the rest of my notification properties.

Comment: Also, I didn't think of it before, but I could use a `ContextThemeWrapper` as well. I think maybe that would be better to use in the `Application` class? This way I'm not using the application context directly.

Comment: from my understanding a ContextthemeWrapper is when you already have a context but what to add multiple themes to it. So this way you can use multiple UI elements from different themes.

Comment: Hm, I thought `ContextThemeWrapper` gave you a new `Context` that acted like the given `Context`, so that you could set a theme without actually altering the original `Context`. At least that is what I got from the `ContextWrapper` description: "Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing the original Context."

Comment: Hope I dont get any side effects .. but works fine.. also need this for notifications.